# WPF monitoring property changes

Tags: c#, wpf

I frequently have the following task:

I have a collection of objects (f.e. Customers) and want to provide the user with an editor for these objects. Typically I have some list control on the left side of the editor and a form on the right side. The form displays the properties of the object that is currently selected on the left side.

Regarding the confirmation of any changes, there are at least two strategies:

- make the editor a modal dialog window and give it OK/Cancel buttons. On OK save all changes for all objects
- give the editor a Save button above or below the form on the right side that would allow the user to confirm changes to the currently selected object.

My question is about the second strategy, implemented as an MVVM application with WPF:

I would like to give my user a feedback that there are unsaved changes. Applications like text editors often solve this by enabling the Save button when any changes occurred and disabling it again once the user pressed it to confirm her/his changes.

If I understand correctly I would have to monitor changes to any bound properties in my form (backed by a model class). Usually my model classes use auto properties (no explicit getters and setters). Do I have to write explicit getters for all my properties to enable the Save button when anything changed, or is there a smarter way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use a [`BindingGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindinggroup?view=netframework-4.7.2) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to write INPC aware getters and setters in your model classes, then another way is to write a equality compare method instead, and then have your save command availability callback call into that to compare the "live" object with the edited one. I'm assuming you have a cloned object that is being edited in order to rollback if the user chooses not to save.

WPF will call it automatically as the user clicks around and types, or you can give it a hint with `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was looking for. I seems to be more efficient to write a CanExecute handler for one command instead of setters for every property. Then again I don't know how costly it will be in the end. CanExecute seems to be called very often. Even a focus change between two form elements triggers it twice, also every typing in TextBoxes! I will see...

Answer (score 4):

Following the MVVM pattern, your ViewModels should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface, than you can easily subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event and monitor properties changes

Comment: Certainly a solution but, as I understand it, it would require explicit setters/getters for all properties while the solution provided by GazTheDestroyer requires only a comparison and one handler. Performance-wise your solution probably wins.